# Xcode Simulator: localhost works, IP-address doesn't

Tags: xcode, apache, xampp

I have installed the XAMPP Apache web server and I want to access an PHP file in my iPhone App (simulator). Now when I try to access it with http://localhost/myphpfile.php it works fine, but when I try to use the IP-address instead of localhost (http://192.168.178.26/myphpfile.php) it doesn't work anymore. The problem just occurs in the simulator. While using the app on my iPhoneI have no problem to access the PHP file via the IP-address.

Answer (score 0):

localhost address should be 127.0.0.1

Comment: That's the loopback IP adress, but 192.168.178.26 is the IP adress of my pc/web server.